# Why can I only pull the "id" attribute but not the "name" from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 files as shown below:

PostVent.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PostLinkStyle.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    legend.standout{font-weight: bold; font-size: 24pt;}
    </style>     
    <title>Post Vent</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- start header div -->
<div id="header">
    <h3>SomeVent</h3>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-8 small-centered columns">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend id="legend">Post Vent</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 columns">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" size="35"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-8 columns">
                            <?php
                            //Include database configuration file
                            include('dbConfig.php');
                            include('index.php');
                            //Get all state data
                            $query = $db->query("SELECT **name** FROM states");
                            //Count total number of rows
                            $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
                            ?>
                            <select name="state" id="state">
                                <option value="">Select State</option>
                                <?php
                                if($rowCount > 0){
                                    while($row = $query->fetch_array()){ 
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    echo '<option value="">States not available</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <select name="county" id="county">
                                <option value="">Select County</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

index.php:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#state').on('change',function(){
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'id='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#county').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#county').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
        }
    });
    $('#county').on('change',function(){
        var countyID = $(this).val();
        if(countyID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'id='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#county').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
    //Get all county data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT name FROM counties...");
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    //Display county list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select County</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">County not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Plus my database config file (I don't think it needs to be shown). I am attempting to dynamically populate the counties dropdown based on selected state.

I am very new at this and put what I have together from a many tutorials available online. My question is this. How come my county menu isn't populating?  I'm trying to post the selected state id attribute to ajax to get the counties with the same id.  Can't see what's wrong.

Comment: looking for `SELECT id,name FROM states` ???

Comment: you are using `SELECT name FROM states` only name in query and printing result for both `echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>';` ???

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you wont get what you want because in your `PostVent.php` the one you are displaying is the `id` and the hidden value is the `name`. It should be:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
```

Syntax of [`<option>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) is `<option value='[Specifies the value to be sent to a server]'>[Label or display value]</option>`

Also your query should be:

```
SELECT id, name FROM states ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't realize I was hiding one.

Comment: An advice as to where to look why my county list wont load? I'm trying to pull up the counties via the selected state id?